# Redirect to Google account picker in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-account

In an AppEngine app, if the user tries to login with a wrong Google account (we check if he's in the database), we'd like to provide a URL so he can log in with another Google account. Without being loged out with the first one (if he has gMail open for example).

At the moment, the app requires the authentication, and if you pick the wrong account, you can never go back to the "login" page.

We use the Appengine Users API in python.

Thanks for helping